# How to use existing terminal session to save output with ANSI escape code like `script` or `screen -L` do?

Tags: gnu-screen, clipboard, konsole, xclip, typescript

I run a python script on `konsole` to print long logging for few hours, then I realized I want to save its output with color, but it's too late to run either `script` or `screen -L` to save the output as color text by keeping ANSI escape code.

I tried [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14694983/1074998) but no luck, i.e. `LD_PRELOAD=./libisatty.so xclip -o -selection clipboard > midnight.log`

Is it possible select existing terminal session and save its existing output with ANSI escape code ?

Answer (score 1):

no - it's too late.  konsole doesn't have a way to get the contents of the screen as characters.  That's why you would have to rely upon other programs (such as **`script`**) to capture the information.

Comment: My konsole settings is "Unlimited scrollback" which claims that "scrollback data will be written unencrypted to temporary files.". And I noticed there are big binary file ~161MB `/tmp/konsole-k16137.history` exists, is it impossible to convert to actual content since it's unencrypted ?

Comment: Good luck with *that* (see [source](https://github.com/KDE/konsole/blob/master/src/History.cpp)).  It seems that they're storing **data structures** there rather than ANSI **text** (you'd need a tool for this, and KDE developers tend to not provide that).